# How does google firebase save users data so that every time the user logs on, the previous work they did on the website is still there?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, user-data

How does google firebase save users data so that every time the user logs on, the previous work they did on the website is still there?

I watched a couple videos and saw that people use the Real-time data base in firebase, is that the solution? I've attempted using a tutorial but it didn't go as planned.

Can someone please tell me how I can make it so that when a user logs onto my website (through a google login -> I've already set up google sign in authentication and firebase receives the users data) and they do something on it (I have a todo list and calendar on it) then when they refresh the page or close the browser window and re-log back on; what they wrote and did on my website is still there?

Also, I need to do it using html or javascript since my website was created using that (and CSS).

Linking a tutorial with your answer would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase is a suite of tools, this suite contains a lite auth system built on Googles IAM service and can hold some limited and restricted data, display name, email, etc.

Firebase also has two main databases for text and information, Realtime and Firestore, both of which use different styles of structured data. Realtime is a giant JSON tree that you can add entries to any location and read without any restrictions other than bandwidth.

Firestore on the other hand is like Google Docs, each "document" can hold up to 1Mb of data in a similar JSON data while being inside a type of virtual folder called a collection.

Both have different ideals and restrictions making the use of both in a project more beneficial rather than choosing one or the other.

To break it down, Realtime has almost no write cost, making it ideal for updating data frequently but does better with intermittent reads due to the read costs scaling per kb.
Firestore on the other hand has low priced reads and higher writes, ideal for data that doesn't update frequently, this is also supported with a limited 1 second update time per document

There is another service called Firebase Storage which can hold data as well but may not suit everyone's needs and has limited use, similar to Dropbox or google drive with a public download URL that is sharable.

Comment: So should I be using firestore hand in hand with firebase?

Comment: There is some confusion since Google Cloud does have its own version of Firestore but it's a crude clone of the Firebase Firestore. You can read about Firebase Firestore here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore

Comment: I'm still very confused. Should I use firebase storage then? And do you have any tutorials that I could follow so that I can get my website to save user changes using firebase?

Comment: When you say 'user changes' what do you mean? and no, most likely storage is not your ideal solution.
You are referencing changes within a website, is this from a web editor or some sort of word editor?
most likely you are interested in Firebase Firestore

Comment: By user changes I mean when a user comes on my website, they can for example add something to their to-do list and even after they refresh or close the tab; their to-do list items are still there. Yes I'm using a web editor + IDE. So Firebase Firestore would be able to save user changes(like if the user adds something to their to-do list or adds an event to their calendar, etc)?

Comment: Easily, you can have a collection of users with a document for each user that is named after their 'uid' in this document, you can hold information for that user and you can store their todo list in it too. there are more techniques available for scaling but that really goes out of the scope of this question.

Comment: if you wouldn't mind, could you accept the answer? it would help me out!

Comment: And I can do that all with Firestore or does Firebases real-time data base also work to do that?

Comment: you can do the same with realtime db, but it won't scale as well for 1-1 reads and writes cost-wise. https://firebase.google.com/pricing

Comment: Alright, thank you very much!